# HTML5 and ASP.Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, html

Is the html output generated in ASP.Net 4.0 is HTML5 Compliant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Asp.net 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010 is compatible with HTML 5. You can download the [**Visual Studio Service pack 1 Beta From** ***Here***](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdevtools/archive/2011/01/27/html5-amp-css3-in-visual-studio-2010-sp1.aspx) for Html 5 and CSS3 intellisense

Check other url's which ca help you to create Html5 Pages.

http://blog.reybango.com/2010/09/21/how-to-create-html5-website-and-page-templates-for-visual-studio-2010/

Answer (score 4):

It is compatible with HTML5, but it is not HTML5.

Check out this thread: http://forums.asp.net/p/1401032/3032617.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ASP.Net controls which render as HTML5 inputs, links, etc, you can create custom controls or use some that are freely available.  I made a suite of them and open-sourced it at [http://html5asp.sourceforge.net](http://html5asp.sourceforge.net/).  The main challenge was getting the inputs to generate HTML with "input type='XXXX'".  If you want to make your own, this is done by overriding AddAttributesToRender and RenderContents.  Please feel free to check out my project for the complete source code or download the binaries.

Comment: ,Definitely i will check them once.Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It is compatible with HTML5. Try below link:

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series